# Delete contents of folders windows\winsxs and windows\Installer in Windows Server Enterprise SP2?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I added the tags `windows-server-2008-r2` and `windows-server-2008` because I didn't see a tag for `Windows Server Enterprise SP2`.

I've seen many articles on using `Disk Cleanup` with `Windows Server 2008 R2` but unfortunately they don't apply to us.

We have `Windows Server Enterprise SP2` (Copyright is 2007) with two folders (`winsxs` and `Installer`) that are 11GB and 5GB in size, respectively. That's over 16GB right there.

When I run Windows' `Disk Cleanup` utility, I notice that the option `Windows Update Cleanup` is not in the list. I also don't see an option that refers to `Installer`.

Is there another way to delete these folders? There are folders in there from 2008. There are literally 10,000 folder under `winsxs` that were created in years 2008 & 2009.

Here's a screenshot of the version of the OS we're using:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

***Don't ever manually delete anything in those folders.***

The first one contains multiple versions of system files and DLLs, so that any program can find the *exact* version it requires, thus solving the long-dreaded "DLL hell" problem. Unfortunately, this has the side effect of the folder contents growing in size each time any update is installed. But manually deleting *anything* from there can and will harm your system, possibly to the point of rendering it unusable.

The second folder stores the Windows Installer files for installed applications, so that they are available if you (or the system) need to repair, modify or uninstall an application. If you remove files from there, next time you try to repair, modify or uninstall an application you will be asked to provide its Windows Installer package, which you will probably not have anymore, or which could be quite difficult to extract from the original installation media or setup files.

Just don't touch anything there, even if it takes up some space. Those files ***need*** to be there in order for your system to work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

`I added the tags windows-server-2008-r2 and windows-server-2008 because I didn't see a tag for Windows Server Enterprise SP2.` - That's because there is no such thing. It's either Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition or it's Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition. It isn't just Windows Server Enterprise Edition. If you're going to ask a question the least you can do is figure out how to figure out what version of Windows you're running.

As for your question, you can use the Windows Component Clean Tool - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351467%28v=WS.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_COMPCLN

**EDIT:**

OK, I get it. Microsoft didn't make it particularly intuitive in Windows Server 2008 to see the Windows version. You can find out by clicking **Help...About** in the screen you posted a picture of or you can find it by running `ver` from a command prompt and cross referencing the build number.

[image]

Comment: A side note, dism /online-cleanup /spsuperseeded can be used if the tool is not installed. (Added as a side note as it do the exact same thing than the tool)

Answer (score -1):

The Windows Update Cleanup is only available for Windows Server 2008 R2 (Windows 7 counterpart) after [installing this update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2852386), you use the the counterpart of Windows Vista which never gets this feature.

To cleanup WinSxS you have to [manually uninstall old updates](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/remove-update#1TC=windows-vista).

To know which updates are no longer needed (superseded), open regedit, and go to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\ComponentDetect\`  Windows stores here each installed component + installed updates. Good candidates are Internet Explorer updates under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\ComponentDetect\amd64_microsoft-windows-ie-htmlrendering_31bf3856ad364e35_0.0.0.0_none_933ba3cd22b12888`

Each new update replaces ALL older GDR Updates. So look for the highest version number and uninstall the older updates. I did this in Vista/7 time and it saved a large amount of space.

To cleanup the `Windows\Installer` folder you can try the 3rd party tool [PatchCleaner](http://www.homedev.com.au/Free/PatchCleaner) which allows to cleanup old unused MSI/MSP files.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Click on `Move` to move the no longer needed files to a network drive, so that in case, the tool has a bug and removing/updating a software requires a MSI/MSP file, you can copy it back.

Comment: "To cleanup WinSxS you have to manually uninstall old updates"... an update never becomes "old", unless a KB article for a newer update *explicitly* says it replaces an old one. But even in this case, manual uninstallation of "old" updates is not something you should do.

Comment: Cleaning up orphaned Windows Installer files *might* be useful, but with newer versions of Windows Installer it has become increasingly uncommon for Windows to just leave MSI/MSP packages around after a program has been *properly* uninstalled ("Properly" being the keyword here).

Comment: In short, both your solutions are risky, difficult, not much useful, and much more likely to damage your system.

Comment: Anyway, I know perfectly well what a superseded update is, and what disk cleanup does (and also how often it gets things wrong, but that's another story): what I explicitly advised against is ***MANUALLY*** removing files and folders there, or ***MANUALLY*** uninstalling updates which you *think* are "old", but whose removal could still have unpredictable results.

Comment: *Even the article you linked* says that "we do not recommend removing updates". Of course they *can* be removed, but there should be a good reason for this, such as "it breaks something", not as "I want more space". And using Disk Cleanup to remove superseded updates is very different than manually uninstalling it; it's actually the exact opposite: after having done that, you won't be done to *revert* to the old update anymore.